# Yaql expression. How can I make two list into json object

Tags: python

I m trying to form json object from two list vn1","vn2","vn3"] and [6,4,5] using below yaql expression

```
yaql> dict(data=>dict(["name","id"].zip(["vn1","vn2","vn3"],[6,4,5])))
{
    "data": {
        "name": "vn1",
        "id": "vn2"
    }
}
```

I would like below output

> {
> "data": [
> {
> "name": "vn1",
> "id": 6
> },
> {
> "name": "vn2",
> "id": 4
> },
> {
> "name": "vn3",
> "id": 5
> }
> ]   }

Answer (score 0):

Your json object resembles a dictionary of lists:

```
# dictionary of empty list
json_dict = { 'data': [] }
label = ['name', 'id']
v = ["vn1","vn2","vn3"]
k = [6,4,5]

# for each value
for i in range(len(v)):
    # add each list entry as dictionarys keys, values
    json_dict['data'].append({ label[0] : v[i], label[1]: k[i] })
```

check it matches your needed json object:

```
json_object = { "data": [ { "name": "vn1", "id": 6 }, { "name": "vn2", "id": 4 }, { "name": "vn3", "id": 5 } ] }

>>> json_dict == json_object
True
```